# Azure DevOps REST API

Tags: c#, visual-studio, .net-core, web-applications, azure-devops-rest-api

I have read the Azure DevOPS REST API documentation and tried to implement it to my Web Application multiple times but to no avail. I have no experience using REST API's and I would appreciate if someone could guide me into the right direction.

I am trying to create a POST Request for Azure DevOps Repositories and wish to create a new repository through the API method. I have read the documentation on this, but I have no idea how to implement this in my own project. I understand how I need to create a connection to the API, but no idea how and where I write the Request Body for this method. I would like to know how I specify the name of the new repository. I'm actually very clueless and have no idea how to use the REST API in general.

I am using Visual Studio with .NET Core 3.0 and plan to use this with React.js

Here's the code I'm working with so far, and I have no idea where to go from here:

```
public class AzureDevOps { 
    public static async void GetRepositories()
    {
        try
        {
            var personalaccesstoken = "PAT_FROM_WEBSITE";

            using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
            {
                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Accept.Add(
                    new System.Net.Http.Headers.MediaTypeWithQualityHeaderValue("application/json"));

                client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                    Convert.ToBase64String(
                        System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                            string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", personalaccesstoken))));

                using (HttpResponseMessage response = await client.GetAsync(
                            "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1"))
                {
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    string responseBody = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    Console.WriteLine(responseBody);
                }
            }
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
        }
    }
}
```

I would appreciate any clarification on this matter, as well as some examples on how to use the REST API. Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your above code is creating an HTTP GET request, (... `await client.GetAsync(` ...) while what it sounds like you need is an HTTP POST request `await client.PostAsync(`: https://blog.jayway.com/2012/03/13/httpclient-makes-get-and-post-very-simple/

Comment: The code is an example of HTTP GET request from the Azure DevOps REST API reference documentation. It should return all repositories available in a specified organization. My task however is to create a POST request to create a new repository on Azure DevOps. I don’t understand how to use the REST API and I can’t seem to find information online that could help me with my problem.

Comment: I just realised that you posted a link to a blog (wasn’t clear to me at first since I am replying on my phone. Will take a look at it later when I get some free time! In the meantime I am also hoping someone has experience with using the Azure DevOps REST API or has any knowledge that could guide me in the right direction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use `POST` method to create a repository. Check the API here:

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/rest/api/azure/devops/git/repositories/create?view=azure-devops-rest-5.1

The code should look like:

```
                var PAT = "xxxxx";

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", PAT))));
                    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1");
                    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent("{\"name\": \"RepositoryName\",\"project\": {\"id\": \"xxxxxxx\"}}", Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result)
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    }
                }
```

**Update:**

```
       var PAT = "xxxxx";
       var body = new
            {
                name = "RepositoryName",
                project = new
                {
                    id = "xxxxxxx"
                }
            };

                using (HttpClient client = new HttpClient())
                {
                    client.DefaultRequestHeaders.Authorization = new AuthenticationHeaderValue("Basic",
                        Convert.ToBase64String(
                            System.Text.ASCIIEncoding.ASCII.GetBytes(
                                string.Format("{0}:{1}", "", PAT))));
                    var requestMessage = new HttpRequestMessage(HttpMethod.Post, "https://dev.azure.com/{organization}/{project}/_apis/git/repositories?api-version=5.1");
                    requestMessage.Content = new StringContent(JsonConvert.SerializeObject(body), Encoding.UTF8, "application/json");
                    using (HttpResponseMessage response = client.SendAsync(requestMessage).Result)
                    {
                        response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();
                    }
                }
```

Comment: What should be written instead of "xxxxxxx" in the requestMessage StringContent? Also, how do I use this POST method in the API Controller or with React? And how do I create a request body for the name of the new repository?

Comment: This worked great! Is there any way I can include the string in StringContent as a json file instead?

Comment: It worked like a charm, thanks! I have created a new thread for a new problem related to reactjs and if you know anything about that, I would greatly appreciate if you could aid me there as well. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60618173/post-request-to-azure-devops-rest-api-with-reactjs